# How to remove multiple versions of androidx annotation in Project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting multiple versions of androidx.annotations (1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0) in my project.

Even after forceful resolution in app level build.gradle file still there are multiple versions. How can I resolve it? I just need a single version (1.2.0)

Same is happening with other libs also like (appcompat, androidx.arch.core etc)

**app level build.gradle**

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "androidx.annotation:annotation:$x_annotation"
        }
    }
```